# syntax error near unexpected token `then' `/dev/null)" if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then'

Tags: linux

I want to source my `~/.bashrc` file but I get the following error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

how do I fix it? this is the part of the `~/.bashrc` that is giving the error

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/arnle/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> 
/dev/null)" if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup" else
    if [ -f "/home/arnle/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/arnle/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" else
        export PATH="/home/arnle/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi 
fi 
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: If its reproducible, file a bug against conda - it apparently wrote this nonsense. Then add a newline before "if" while you wait for a fix.

Comment: thank! but adding a newline before "if" gives me the following error:
```
bash: command substitution: line 106: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: command substitution: line 106: `'/home/arnle/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook'
```

Comment: Please use `shellcheck.net` to check syntax -- either download it, or use it in a browser. Every syntax error it flags has a page of explanation online.

Comment: @arnle, oh, that's the newline after the redirection `2>`. That's an error, the filename has to come on the same line. I didn't notice that when writing the answer under the other question, it just looked like visual word wrapping. (I added there now too, just for completeness.) Not to put it too finely, the newlines in that script seem somewhat badly messed up. Using shellcheck is a good idea, just that it's not perfect. It just says "^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this redirection. Fix to allow more checks" about that one, and the text behind the link doesn't really explain it.